# How to rearrange pixels when making images

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, pixel

I am working with parquet files in jupyter notebook using python to make images. I am trying to make an image with each row of data. Right now, I am reshaping each image to be 10  pixels by 26, and I was wondering how I could convert this. I would like to move the right half of the image to be under the left half, resulting in 20 pixels by 13. Thank you! I have attached a sample of my code:

```
values = data.iloc[i].values[1:]
x = np.reshape(values, (10,26))
img = Image.fromarray(x, "L")
```

I tried:
`x = np.reshape(values, (9,13))` but it does not look like it is putting the right half under the left half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array = np.random.randn(10*26).reshape(10,26)
top = array[:,:13] # Take all rows until the 13th column
bottom = array[:,13:] # Take all rows after the 13th column
stacked = np.vstack([top,bottom]) # Stack top and bottom
print(stacked.shape) # ensure desired output dimensions
>>> (20, 13)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!